# String formatting `bytes` objects gives me a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing in data sending in Python and have a problem with this code for the SERVER:

```
from socket import *
from time import ctime

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

udpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
udpSerSock.bind(ADDR)

while True:
  print("waitin for msg...")
  data, addr = udpSerSock.recvfrom(BUFSIZ)
  udpSerSock.sendto("[%s] %s" % (ctime().encode("utf-8"), data), addr)
  print("...received from and returned to ")

udpSerSock.close()
```

The problem is in this line

```
udpSerSock.sendto("[%s] %s" % (ctime().encode("utf-8"), data), addr)
```

Whenever I send a message to the server it crashes."str does not support the buffer interface"
How to change that line?
I understand that the problem is with "[%s] %s", but do not know how to resolve it.

UPD>>>>>
Resolved it. The messy way:

```
udpSerSock.sendto(ctime().encode("utf-8") + b" " + data, addr)
```

Comment: Why not `udpSerSock.sendto("[{}] {}".format(ctime(), data.decode()).encode('utf-8'), addr)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're building a string. So even though you're putting `bytes` objects into it, it's still a string. What you need to do instead is to build your string, then encode the whole thing.

```
msg = "[{}] {}".format(ctime(), data.decode())
b_msg = msg.encode()
udpSerSock.sendto(b_msg, addr)
```

You can diagnose this pretty easily by doing:

```
>>> your_msg = "[%s] %s" % (ctime().encode('utf-8'), data)
>>> print(type(your_msg))
<class 'str'>
>>> print(your_msg)
[b'Tue Apr 14 20:20:18 2015'] b'some data here' # note the multiple b'...'s
```

While if you build the whole string first then encode it, you get

```
>>> my_msg = "[{}] {}".format(ctime(), data.decode()).encode()
>>> print(type(my_msg))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(my_msg)
b'[Tue Apr 14 20:21:38 2015] some data here' # note the singular b'...'
```